# How to do a simple mail merge in OpenOffice

Tags: c#, c++, com, openoffice.org, ole

I need to do a simple mail merge in OpenOffice using C++, VBScript, VB.Net or C# via OLE or native API. Are there any good examples available?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I haven't come up with a solution I'm really happy with but here are some notes:

- Q. What is the OO API for mail merge?

  A. http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/MailMerge.html
- Q. What support groups?

  A. http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=20
- Q. Sample code?

  A. http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=946&p=3778&hilit=mail+merge#p3778

  http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=8088&p=38017&hilit=mail+merge#p38017
- Q. Any more examples?

  A. file:///C:/Program%20Files/OpenOffice.org_2.4_SDK/examples/examples.html (comes with the SDK)

  http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?p=94970
- Q. How do I build the examples?

  A. e.g., for WriterDemo (C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org_2.4_SDK\examples\CLI\VB.NET\WriterDemo)

  1. Add references to everything in here: C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org    2.4\program\assembly
  2. That is cli_basetypes, cli_cppuhelper, cli_types, cli_ure
- Q. Does OO use the same separate data/document file for mail merge?

  A. It allows for a range of data sources including csv files
- Q. Does OO allow you to merge to all the different types (fax, email, new document printer)?

  A. You can merge to a new document, print and email
- Q. Can you add custom fields?

  A. Yes
- Q. How do you create a new document in VB.Net?

  A.

  ```
          Dim xContext As XComponentContext

          xContext = Bootstrap.bootstrap()

          Dim xFactory As XMultiServiceFactory
          xFactory = DirectCast(xContext.getServiceManager(), _
              XMultiServiceFactory)

          'Create the Desktop
          Dim xDesktop As unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop
          xDesktop = DirectCast(xFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop"), _
              unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XDesktop)

          'Open a new empty writer document
          Dim xComponentLoader As unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader
          xComponentLoader = DirectCast(xDesktop, unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader)
          Dim arProps() As unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue = _
              New unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue() {}
          Dim xComponent As unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XComponent
          xComponent = xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL( _
              "private:factory/swriter", "_blank", 0, arProps)
          Dim xTextDocument As unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument
          xTextDocument = DirectCast(xComponent, unoidl.com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument)
  ```
- Q. How do you save the document?

  A.

  ```
          Dim storer As unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XStorable = DirectCast(xTextDocument, unoidl.com.sun.star.frame.XStorable)
          arProps = New unoidl.com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue() {}
          storer.storeToURL("file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/OpenOffice Investigation/saved doc.odt", arProps)
  ```
- Q. How do you Open the document?

  A.

  ```
          Dim xComponent As unoidl.com.sun.star.lang.XComponent
          xComponent = xComponentLoader.loadComponentFromURL( _
              "file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/OpenOffice Investigation/saved doc.odt", "_blank", 0, arProps)
  ```
- Q. How do you initiate a mail merge in VB.Net?

  A.

  1. Don't know. This functionality is in the API reference but is missing from the IDL. We may be slightly screwed. Assuming the API was working, it looks like running a merge is fairly simple.
  2. In VBScript:

     Set objServiceManager = WScript.CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")

     'Now set up a new MailMerge using the settings extracted from that doc
     Set oMailMerge = objServiceManager.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.MailMerge")

     oMailMerge.DocumentURL = "file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/OpenOffice Investigation/mail merged.odt"
     oMailMerge.DataSourceName = "adds"
     oMailMerge.CommandType = 0 ' http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/MailMerge.html#CommandType
     oMailMerge.Command = "adds"
     oMailMerge.OutputType = 2 ' http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/MailMerge.html#OutputType
     oMailMerge.execute(Array())
  3. In VB.Net (Option Strict Off)

     ```
         Dim t_OOo As Type
         t_OOo = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
         Dim objServiceManager As Object
         objServiceManager = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t_OOo)

         Dim oMailMerge As Object
         oMailMerge = t_OOo.InvokeMember("createInstance", _
                         BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, _
                         objServiceManager, New [Object]() {"com.sun.star.text.MailMerge"})

         'Now set up a new MailMerge using the settings extracted from that doc
         oMailMerge.DocumentURL = "file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/OpenOffice Investigation/mail merged.odt"
         oMailMerge.DataSourceName = "adds"
         oMailMerge.CommandType = 0 ' http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/MailMerge.html#CommandType
         oMailMerge.Command = "adds"
         oMailMerge.OutputType = 2 ' http://api.openoffice.org/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/MailMerge.html#OutputType
         oMailMerge.execute(New [Object]() {})
     ```
  4. The same thing but with Option Strict On (doesn't work)

     ```
         Dim t_OOo As Type
         t_OOo = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
         Dim objServiceManager As Object
         objServiceManager = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t_OOo)

         Dim oMailMerge As Object
         oMailMerge = t_OOo.InvokeMember("createInstance", _
                         BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, _
                         objServiceManager, New [Object]() {"com.sun.star.text.MailMerge"})

         'Now set up a new MailMerge using the settings extracted from that doc
         oMailMerge.GetType().InvokeMember("DocumentURL", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, oMailMerge, New [Object]() {"file:///C:/Users/me/Desktop/OpenOffice Investigation/mail merged.odt"})
         oMailMerge.GetType().InvokeMember("DataSourceName", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, oMailMerge, New [Object]() {"adds"})
         oMailMerge.GetType().InvokeMember("CommandType", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, oMailMerge, New [Object]() {0})
         oMailMerge.GetType().InvokeMember("Command", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, oMailMerge, New [Object]() {"adds"})
         oMailMerge.GetType().InvokeMember("OutputType", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, oMailMerge, New [Object]() {2})
         oMailMerge.GetType().InvokeMember("Execute", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod Or BindingFlags.IgnoreReturn, Nothing, oMailMerge, New [Object]() {}) ' this line fails with a type mismatch error
     ```

Comment: Don't use reflection in .NET to create an instance of MailMerge. I had been doing this too based on this answer and while it worked for merging to a file, trying to merge to the printer by setting the PrintOptions property would fail with a variantToAny conversion exception. The proper way seems to be cast the return of the context's getServiceManager() as an XMultiComponentFactory, then call createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.text.MailMerge", context) to create a MailMerge object. Cast that as an XPropertySet and set the MailMerge's properties with XPropertySet's methods.

Comment: Also, although you shouldn't use reflection here, regarding the line throwing the type mismatch exception on with the call to Execute, it is because you are passing the wrong argument. XJob's Execute method requires passing a sequence of NamedValue objects, which means you need to pass new object[] { new NamedValue[] { } } rather than just new object[] { }

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at **[Apache OpenOffice API](http://api.openoffice.org)**. A project for creating an API for Open Office. A few languages they said to support are: C++, Java, Python, CLI, StarBasic, JavaScript and OLE.

[Java Example of a mailmerge in OpenOffice](http://codesnippets.services.openoffice.org/Writer/Writer.MailMerge.snip).