# LibreOffice Mail Merge with Java

Tags: java, libreoffice, mailmerge

I'm trying to use the libre office mail merge functionality automatically from an java application.

I have tried to install the libreoffice sdk but without success because they require software that is not available anymore (e.g. zip-tools). Anyway I was able to get the jar files (jurtl-3.2.1.jar, ridl-3.2.1.jar, unoil-3.2.1.jar and juh-3.2.1.jar) from the maven repository.

With this jar files I was able to reproduce a lot of examples which are provided here http://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#Java_examples

Also in the LibreOffice API documentation a service named 'MailMerge' is listed (see here http://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1text_1_1MailMerge.html)

But in none of the jar's this service class is available, the only instance available for me is MailMergeType.

I'm able to open an *.odt templatefile within my javacode and the next step would be to create an instance of the mail merge service and pass a *.csv datasourcefile to the mail merge service.

At the API documentation some functions are listed which could help me but as I said before I'm not able to get access to this service class because its simply not exist in the provided jar files.

Do anybody know how I can get access to the mail merge service for libreoffice?

If you need more information about my environment just ask.

Sincerly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this code from 2004](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/openoffice/ooo-site/trunk/content/api/Examples/Snippets/Writer/Writer.MailMerge.snip), apparently you can simply use Java's `Object` class.  Here are a few snippets from that code:

```
Object mmservice = null;
try {
    // Create an instance of the MailMerge service
    mmservice = mxMCF.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.text.MailMerge", mxComponentContext);
}
// Get the XPropertySet interface of the mmservice object
XPropertySet oObjProps = (XPropertySet)
    UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XPropertySet.class, mmservice);
try {
    // Set up the properties for the MailMerge command
    oObjProps.setPropertyValue("DataSourceName", mDataSourceName);
}
// Get XJob interface from MailMerge service and call execute on it
XJob job = (XJob) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XJob.class, mmservice);
try {
    job.execute(new NamedValue[0]);
}
```

See also [How to do a simple mail merge in OpenOffice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38842/how-to-do-a-simple-mail-merge-in-openoffice).

Regarding a source for the old zip tools, try `zip.exe` from http://www.willus.com/archive/zip64/.

Comment: Hello Jim, you are completly right, I had took a wrong turn in my thinking about how this should work. Also I have set this properties before executing the job "DocumentURL" "DataSourceName" "CommandType" "Command" "OutputType" "OutputURL" and "FileNamePrefix". Thank you